# Endless scrolling stops loading results on 6th page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a endless scrolling on the index, and there's over two hundred users in the database. It's setup to show four users per page, the most pages I can scroll down to is 6. Does someone know why it's not loading the other pages?

User Controller:

```
  def index
    @user = current_user
    @search = Search.new
    page = params[:page] || 1
    @order = params[:order] || ['age', 'created_at', 'birthday', 'username'].shuffle.first
     if @user.present?
        @users = User.search(:without => {:user_id => @user.id}, :page => page, :per_page => 4, :order => "#{@order} DESC")
     else
        @users = User.search(:page => page, :per_page => 4, :order => "#{@order} DESC")
     end

     @page = page    
    if request.xhr?
        render :partial => 'user', :layout => false, :collection => @users
    else
        render layout: 'new_application'    
    end
  end
```

Log report:

```
Aug 01 09:44:01 website app/web.1:  Started GET "/" for 84.53.163.847 at 2015-08-01 16:44:00 +0000 
Aug 01 09:44:01 website app/web.1:  Started GET "/" for 84.53.163.847 at 2015-08-01 16:44:00 +0000 
Aug 01 09:44:01 website app/web.1:  Processing by UsersController#index as HTML 
Aug 01 09:44:01 website app/web.1:  Processing by UsersController#index as HTML 
Aug 01 09:44:01 website app/web.1:    Rendered users/_user.html.slim (98.4ms) 
Aug 01 09:44:01 website app/web.1:    Rendered users/_user.html.slim (98.4ms) 
Aug 01 09:44:01 website app/web.1:    Rendered contacts/_form.html.slim (1.3ms) 
Aug 01 09:44:01 website app/web.1:    Rendered contacts/_form.html.slim (1.3ms) 
Aug 01 09:44:01 website app/web.1:    Rendered contacts/_form.html.slim (71.8ms) 
Aug 01 09:44:01 website app/web.1:    Rendered contacts/_form.html.slim (71.8ms) 
Aug 01 09:44:01 website app/web.1:    Rendered users/index.html.slim within layouts/new_application (184.9ms) 
Aug 01 09:44:01 website app/web.1:    Rendered users/index.html.slim within layouts/new_application (184.9ms) 
Aug 01 09:44:01 website app/web.1:    Rendered letsgos/_form.html.erb (1.1ms) 
Aug 01 09:44:01 website app/web.1:    Rendered letsgos/_form.html.erb (1.1ms) 
Aug 01 09:44:01 website app/web.1:    Rendered shared/_header.html.slim (13.6ms) 
Aug 01 09:44:01 website app/web.1:    Rendered shared/_header.html.slim (13.6ms) 
Aug 01 09:44:01 website app/web.1:  Completed 200 OK in 205ms (Views: 125.7ms | ActiveRecord: 76.5ms) 
Aug 01 09:44:01 website app/web.1:  Completed 200 OK in 205ms (Views: 125.7ms | ActiveRecord: 76.5ms) 
Aug 01 09:44:01 website heroku/router:  at=info method=GET path="/" host=website.com request_id=9ca1f8ad-e5f2-4711-a222-de8b5371df5b fwd="84.53.163.847" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=213ms status=200 bytes=27631 
Aug 01 09:44:01 website heroku/router:  at=info method=GET path="/assets/sbg4.jpg" host=website.com request_id=33d17a4f-ec69-417a-b9cd-faaddb830531 fwd="84.53.163.847" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=19ms status=200 bytes=347627 
Aug 01 09:44:04 website heroku/router:  at=info method=GET path="/users?page=2&order=age" host=website.com request_id=52e20cb4-b82a-4da7-a92b-c4db58606466 fwd="84.53.163.847" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=95ms status=200 bytes=5471 
Aug 01 09:44:04 website app/web.1:  Started GET "/users?page=2&order=age" for 84.53.163.847 at 2015-08-01 16:44:04 +0000 
Aug 01 09:44:04 website app/web.1:  Started GET "/users?page=2&order=age" for 84.53.163.847 at 2015-08-01 16:44:04 +0000 
Aug 01 09:44:04 website app/web.1:  Processing by UsersController#index as */* 
Aug 01 09:44:04 website app/web.1:  Processing by UsersController#index as */* 
Aug 01 09:44:04 website app/web.1:    Parameters: {"page"=>"2", "order"=>"age"} 
Aug 01 09:44:04 website app/web.1:    Parameters: {"page"=>"2", "order"=>"age"} 
Aug 01 09:44:04 website app/web.1:    Rendered users/_user.html.slim (76.8ms) 
Aug 01 09:44:04 website app/web.1:    Rendered users/_user.html.slim (76.8ms) 
Aug 01 09:44:04 website app/web.1:  Completed 200 OK in 90ms (Views: 33.2ms | ActiveRecord: 54.1ms) 
Aug 01 09:44:04 website app/web.1:  Completed 200 OK in 90ms (Views: 33.2ms | ActiveRecord: 54.1ms) 
Aug 01 09:44:07 website app/web.1:  Started GET "/users?page=3&order=age" for 84.53.163.847 at 2015-08-01 16:44:06 +0000 
Aug 01 09:44:07 website heroku/router:  at=info method=GET path="/users?page=3&order=age" host=website.com request_id=131a8cbc-54e8-43e4-9a4c-d7faf136fa5d fwd="84.53.163.847" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=107ms status=200 bytes=5527 
Aug 01 09:44:07 website app/web.1:  Started GET "/users?page=3&order=age" for 84.53.163.847 at 2015-08-01 16:44:06 +0000 
Aug 01 09:44:07 website app/web.1:  Processing by UsersController#index as */* 
Aug 01 09:44:07 website app/web.1:  Processing by UsersController#index as */* 
Aug 01 09:44:07 website app/web.1:    Parameters: {"page"=>"3", "order"=>"age"} 
Aug 01 09:44:07 website app/web.1:    Parameters: {"page"=>"3", "order"=>"age"} 
Aug 01 09:44:07 website app/web.1:    Rendered users/_user.html.slim (64.6ms) 
Aug 01 09:44:07 website app/web.1:    Rendered users/_user.html.slim (64.6ms) 
Aug 01 09:44:07 website app/web.1:  Completed 200 OK in 82ms (Views: 37.7ms | ActiveRecord: 42.6ms) 
Aug 01 09:44:07 website app/web.1:  Completed 200 OK in 82ms (Views: 37.7ms | ActiveRecord: 42.6ms) 
Aug 01 09:44:09 website heroku/router:  at=info method=GET path="/users?page=4&order=age" host=website.com request_id=2abbca51-b489-48fb-a8be-f31865ade053 fwd="84.53.163.847" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=116ms status=200 bytes=5527 
Aug 01 09:44:09 website app/web.1:  Started GET "/users?page=4&order=age" for 84.53.163.847 at 2015-08-01 16:44:09 +0000 
Aug 01 09:44:09 website app/web.1:  Started GET "/users?page=4&order=age" for 84.53.163.847 at 2015-08-01 16:44:09 +0000 
Aug 01 09:44:09 website app/web.1:  Processing by UsersController#index as */* 
Aug 01 09:44:09 website app/web.1:  Processing by UsersController#index as */* 
Aug 01 09:44:09 website app/web.1:    Parameters: {"page"=>"4", "order"=>"age"} 
Aug 01 09:44:09 website app/web.1:    Parameters: {"page"=>"4", "order"=>"age"} 
Aug 01 09:44:09 website app/web.1:    Rendered users/_user.html.slim (88.4ms) 
Aug 01 09:44:09 website app/web.1:    Rendered users/_user.html.slim (88.4ms) 
Aug 01 09:44:09 website app/web.1:  Completed 200 OK in 101ms (Views: 32.1ms | ActiveRecord: 66.2ms) 
Aug 01 09:44:09 website app/web.1:  Completed 200 OK in 101ms (Views: 32.1ms | ActiveRecord: 66.2ms) 
Aug 01 09:44:11 website app/web.1:  Started GET "/users?page=5&order=age" for 84.53.163.847 at 2015-08-01 16:44:10 +0000 
Aug 01 09:44:11 website heroku/router:  at=info method=GET path="/users?page=5&order=age" host=website.com request_id=e5e8fbc6-6b6b-4a91-982d-54944d2ca3e6 fwd="84.53.163.847" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=111ms status=200 bytes=5500 
Aug 01 09:44:11 website app/web.1:  Started GET "/users?page=5&order=age" for 84.53.163.847 at 2015-08-01 16:44:10 +0000 
Aug 01 09:44:11 website app/web.1:  Processing by UsersController#index as */* 
Aug 01 09:44:11 website app/web.1:  Processing by UsersController#index as */* 
Aug 01 09:44:11 website app/web.1:    Parameters: {"page"=>"5", "order"=>"age"} 
Aug 01 09:44:11 website app/web.1:    Parameters: {"page"=>"5", "order"=>"age"} 
Aug 01 09:44:11 website app/web.1:    Rendered users/_user.html.slim (92.2ms) 
Aug 01 09:44:11 website app/web.1:    Rendered users/_user.html.slim (92.2ms) 
Aug 01 09:44:11 website app/web.1:  Completed 200 OK in 104ms (Views: 31.7ms | ActiveRecord: 70.5ms) 
Aug 01 09:44:11 website app/web.1:  Completed 200 OK in 104ms (Views: 31.7ms | ActiveRecord: 70.5ms) 
Aug 01 09:44:12 website heroku/router:  at=info method=GET path="/users?page=6&order=age" host=website.com request_id=52fdfce3-576c-41d0-a711-af1173bb3528 fwd="84.53.163.847" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=133ms status=200 bytes=4321 
Aug 01 09:44:12 website app/web.1:  Started GET "/users?page=6&order=age" for 84.53.163.847 at 2015-08-01 16:44:12 +0000 
Aug 01 09:44:13 website app/web.1:  Started GET "/users?page=6&order=age" for 84.53.163.847 at 2015-08-01 16:44:12 +0000 
Aug 01 09:44:13 website app/web.1:  Processing by UsersController#index as */* 
Aug 01 09:44:13 website app/web.1:  Processing by UsersController#index as */* 
Aug 01 09:44:13 website app/web.1:    Parameters: {"page"=>"6", "order"=>"age"} 
Aug 01 09:44:13 website app/web.1:    Parameters: {"page"=>"6", "order"=>"age"} 
Aug 01 09:44:13 website app/web.1:    Rendered users/_user.html.slim (97.4ms) 
Aug 01 09:44:13 website app/web.1:    Rendered users/_user.html.slim (97.4ms) 
Aug 01 09:44:13 website app/web.1:  Completed 200 OK in 124ms (Views: 38.7ms | ActiveRecord: 82.5ms) 
Aug 01 09:44:13 website app/web.1:  Completed 200 OK in 124ms (Views: 38.7ms | ActiveRecord: 82.5ms)
```

index.html.slim:

```
function getMoreRecords(){
    var pageOffset = $('#more_users').val();
    var order = "#{@order}";
    $('#more_button').hide();
    var url = "/users?"+"page=" + pageOffset + "&order=" + order;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: 'GET',
        success: function(html_data){
            // make jQuery object from HTML string
            var $moreBlocks = jQuery( html_data );
            $moreBlocks.css('display','none');
            $(".box_detail").append($moreBlocks).imagesLoaded(
                    function(){
                        $moreBlocks.fadeIn(1000);
                        $(".box_detail").masonry('appended', $moreBlocks);

                        isFetchingPics = false;
                    }
                );        
            Cufon.refresh();
            $( ".common_box" ).mouseenter(function() {
              $(this).find(".btn_link").show();
            }).mouseleave(function() {
              $(this).find(".btn_link").hide();
            });
            if($moreBlocks.length == 4){
                $('#more_users').val((parseInt(pageOffset) + 1));
                $('#more_button').show();
            }
            $('.message_btn').magnificPopup();
            $('.report_btn').magnificPopup();
            $('.message_btn').click(function () {
              var user_id = $(this).data('user');
              $('#user').val(user_id);
              var avatar_url = $("#image_" + user_id).attr('src');
              var username = $("#name_" + user_id).val();
              var age = $("#age_" + user_id).val();
              var gender = $("#gender_" + user_id).val();
              var sexuality = $("#sexuality_" + user_id).val();
              var city = $("#city_" + user_id).val();
              var state = $("#state_" + user_id).val();
              var html_content = "<div class=\"commoon_sec\">" +
                          "<div class=\"left_sec\"><img alt=\"Popup baby\" src=\"" + avatar_url + "\"></div>" +
                          "<div class=\"right_sec\" style=\"position:relative;\">" +
                          "<div class=\"top_box\" style=\"position:absolute; border: 1px solid #cccccc; width: 456px; border-radius: 6px; height: 140px; background-color: #F7F7F7;\">" +
                          "<div class=\"left_box\" style=\"float:right; text-align:left; width: 68%;\">" +
                          "<h2>" + username + "</h2><h3>" + age + ", " + gender + ", " + sexuality + "</br>" +
                          city + ", " + state + "</h3></div></div></div></div>";
              $("div.common_sec").html(html_content);
              Cufon.refresh();
            });
            $('form#message_form').bind('ajax:success', function(evt, data, status, xhr){
                $.magnificPopup.close()  
              });
            $('.save_btn').magnificPopup();
        }

    });
 }

 $("#relegion, #gender, #children, #ethnicity").on('change', function(){
    return false;       
 });

 $("#basic_search input.text_input").on('keyup', function(){
   $("input.adv_text_input").val(this.value);
 });

 $("#reset_form").on('click', function(){
   $("form#adv_search").trigger('reset');
   $("form#basic_search").trigger('reset');  
   $("input.adv_text_input").val("");
 });

 $("#basic_search").submit(function(e){
    $('form#adv_search').submit();
    e.preventDefault();
 });

 $("#save_search").on("click", function () {
      $('form#adv_search').attr('action', "/searches/save_searches");
      $('form#adv_search').submit();
      e.preventDefault();
  });
```

_user.html.slim:

```
- if user.avatar.present?
  - style_class = {"1" => "box1", "2" => "box2", "3" => "box3", "4" => "box1"}
  - style_type = {"1" => "similar", "2" => "profile", "3" => "box", "4" => "similar"}
  - shuffle_array = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
  - my_index = shuffle_array.rotate(@page.to_i || ((user_counter+1).to_f/4.to_f).ceil)
  - my_style = @page.present? ? style_type[my_index[user_counter]] : style_type[my_index[((user_counter+1).to_f%4.to_f).ceil]]
  - my_style_class = @page.present? ? style_class[my_index[user_counter]] : style_class[my_index[((user_counter+1).to_f%4.to_f).ceil]]
  div class="common_box #{my_style_class}" data-user-id="#{user.username}" id="#{user.username}"
    .img_box
      = link_to user do
        = image_tag user.avatar.try(:image_url, my_style), id: "image_#{user.id}"
      input type="hidden" id="name_#{user.id}" value="#{user.username}"
      input type="hidden" id="age_#{user.id}" value="#{user.age}"
      input type="hidden" id="gender_#{user.id}" value="#{user.gender}"
      input type="hidden" id="sexuality_#{user.id}" value="#{user.sexuality}"
      input type="hidden" id="city_#{user.id}" value="#{user.location.try(:city)}"
      input type="hidden" id="state_#{user.id}" value="#{user.location.try(:state)}"
      -if @user.present?
        ul.btn_link.hide
          li
            a.message_btn  href="#" data-user="#{user.id}"  data-mfp-src='#message_me'   Message
          li id="set_follow_#{user.username}"
            - if current_user.following?(user)
                = link_to "UnFollow", users_set_follow_path(:id => user), class: 'users save_btn', remote: true
            -else
                = link_to "Follow", users_set_follow_path(:id => user), class: 'users save_btn', remote: true
          li
            a.report_btn href="#" data-mfp-src='#report_me'  Report
    .img_detail
      small years
      .circle
        span.age_box class="#{user.gender == 'Male' ? '': 'pink'}" = user.age
      h3 class="#{user.gender == 'Male' ? '' : 'pink'}" = user.username
      h4 
        = user.address
      div class= "#{user.gender == 'Male' ? 'green_corner': 'pink_corner'}"
        =image_tag "#{user.gender == 'Male' ? 'side_curv.png': 'curv_2.png'}"
```

Comment: What does your JavaScript look like? Both your ajax call and your js.erb file.

Comment: @RyanK Added, you can see code from the index. I'm thinking this is unrelated to Cufon.refresh. As the code was working before other issues pop up in the app that I had to repair. I'm going to continue inspecting to see what could be causing the problem, as it could be something from a controller preventing it and not the javascript.

Comment: I've never worked with (or even heard of) slim, so I'm not familiar with the syntax. However, you have the line `if($moreBlocks.length == 4)`. I'm not sure if increasing that number would work, but it seems like that is the important line.

Comment: That's for the amount of user blocks to show per row. The limit is 4 per row. It could be something with it not detecting users avatars (not sure why it wouldn't) which is why it wouldn't show on the index. Will dig deeper into that. All user profiles show with their avatar, but my only guess is Photos is blocking all profiles from loading.

Comment: If you open `/users?page=10&order=age` in your browser, does it show correct response?

Comment: by the way: `:order => "#{@order} DESC"` – does you intend SQL injection vulnerability to be here?

Comment: @EugZol yes the correct response is shown, but that too shows only 6 pages while scrolling.

Comment: @xps15z Let us stop for a second. When you visit `/users?page=10&order=age` you should see 10th page, not 1st. Do you see that? And then you can scroll down from 10th to 16th page?

Comment: @EugZol It starts at page 10, then when you scroll takes you to pages 2-6.

Comment: What problem do you see? Is it that the `more_button` is not shown or that the response for 7th page isn't received or something else?

Comment: @EdBallot the response for the 7th page isn't received.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is to close the topic. It was not a javascript issue. I rollback heroku, removed the last 10 users added to database, and all is fine. Was never able to locate the culprit, but none of the provided answers were suitable.

Thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 1):

In your AJAX call, try to pass the parameters (page, order) as a data object, and not as part of the url like so:

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: {page: PAGE_GOES_HERE, order: ORDER_HERE}
        method: 'GET',
        success: function(html_data){
           ...
        }
});
```

Comment: If you look at the output of the server log, the params seem to be just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use Chrome or FF developer tools, set a breakpoint on the first line of `getMoreRecords` as well as the `success` callback and step through your JavaScript code.
Instead of setting a breakpoint, you can also add a `debugger;` statement into the JavaScript.

Also, have a look at the error console and the Network tab in the developer tools and check if you see anything suspicious there.

If this doesn't help, it should at least give you some more information to update your question.

Comment: I don't think it's a javascript issue as I have inspected it carefully and I see zero issues. I feel that it's an issue with the controller and loading the users in a random order.

Comment: Your console didn't show any GET request for page 7, so why do you think it's the controller? And no matter where the mistake is, the JavaScript would still be the best point to start debugging.